# Possible to generate heatmaps using tflite models?

Tags: keras, tflite

To save server space I convert keras models (h5) to tflite format and I'd like to create heatmaps / saliency maps with the tflite models. Its easy to create a heatmap with a keras model, but tflite I have not seen any examples. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why does the type of model matter? It's all about processing the output. What's hindering to just process the output in the same way?

Comment: We have many trained models and have limited space on our server so we convert to a smaller tflite format. We want to be able to generate heatmaps from new images down the track.